PlayerGUI will not show up on mobile
I'm creating a restaurant game. When you click the menu, which is a part in workspace, it should open up a UI frame that has some buttons on it. They are connected by two remote events, one for making the menu visible, and one for making it invisible.
Everything works perfectly on PC, but the UI does not show up on mobile. I playtested with my friends and found clicking works on mobile, but the UI shows up on my screen and not their mobile screens.
Im confused because

I'm using local player in a local script, and referring to PlayerGUI not StarterGUI, why would their menu show up for me?
Why won't UI show up on mobile?

Here is the Code, I'm a begginner lol:
--this is a local script
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local menuUI = player.PlayerGui.ScreenGUI.Menu

menuUI.Visible= false

game.ReplicatedStorage.MenuOpen.OnClientEvent:Connect(function()
    menuUI.Visible = true
end)

game.ReplicatedStorage.MenuClose.OnClientEvent:Connect(function()
    menuUI.Visible = false
end)

And here is the server side script
--this is a server script
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local Menuboard = script.parent
local ClickDetector = Menuboard.ClickDetector
local OpenRemoteEvent = ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild("MenuOpen")
local CloseRemoteEvent = ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild("MenuClose")

--reopening
local clickcount = 0

ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    if clickcount ==0 then
        print("Menu clicked")
        OpenRemoteEvent:FireAllClients()
        clickcount = clickcount + 1
    else 
        CloseRemoteEvent:FireAllClients()
        clickcount = clickcount - 1
    end
    
    
end)

I've tested different variations so many times, please tell me if you have any ideas.
I've tested different variations so many times, please tell me if you have any ideas.
If the error is in the localscript, it might be that when I listened to the event, I didn't pass any variables in the function()? I'm not quite sure how passing variables work.

What does the UI look like? And how did you position elements? Did you hard code positions, or did you use relative sizing layouts? Could you share what your Position and Size UDim2 values look like?
